# how to fix this error:ddl statement interferred with query replan?

Tags: sql, vertica

database : vertica
when I use `insert into.....select....` statement to add data, following error occurred:

> notice : error encounterred in contriant validation
>   error : ddl statement interferred with query plan
>   hint : please reissue query

Comment: It looks like you hand typed this error. Can you please copy and paste the exact error? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error, although it is not the actual error, is pretty self explanatory. You tried to issue an `INSERT` statement, but there was another DDL statement that interfered (was holding a lock on the table) at the same time and so your `INSERT` statement was killed.

At this point you probably won't be able to see it any more, but in the future when you see this error, take note of the time that the statement was executed, then query the `v_monitor.query_requests` system table to see what other DDL statements were being executed at the same time.

If this was just an ad hoc `INSERT` statement, then the solution is to do exactly what the Vertica notice message said, re-issue the query. If this is part of a script or application logic, then you need to handle this error accordingly and add the logic to re-issue the statement again if this error is thrown.